# Find out in which kind of archive am I

Tags: posts, page-template, archives

in `archive.php` file, I want to know, which type of archive I i'm in. For example, if I i'm in archive for category **Personal** I'd like to be able to display it in header of the archive. Of course, I can create file like `category-12.php`, `category-13.php` ... and then harcode it in the file, but it doesn't seem to be very good example of code reuse.
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect `get_queried_object()`.

On an archive for the category `Uncategorized` you get something like …

```
stdClass Object
(
    [term_id] => 1
    [name] => Uncategorized
    [slug] => uncategorized
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 1
    [taxonomy] => category
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 0
    [count] => 8
    [cat_ID] => 1
    [category_count] => 8
    [category_description] => 
    [cat_name] => Uncategorized
    [category_nicename] => uncategorized
    [category_parent] => 0
)
```

… and on an archive for the tag `test` …

```
stdClass Object
(
    [term_id] => 18
    [name] => test
    [slug] => test-2
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 18
    [taxonomy] => post_tag
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 0
    [count] => 1
)
```

So you can test if a property `taxonomy` for that object exists and what the value is. Then adjust your template.